# Why is this exception outputting from my Iterator search?

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I am receiving an ConcurrentModificationException when trying to use Iterator to search for a specific Integer.

I don't know why it's there. Any research I've looked into says it's an exception that appears when I try to edit the list inside a for loop. I am not doing that, in fact I'm not even editing the list in the Iterator.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
private ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();

public void search(int input) {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (input == iterator.next()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
       }
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchList sl = new SearchList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sl.list.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(sl.list);

    sl.search(6);
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
6
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

````
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
    at SearchList.search(SearchList.java:23)
    at SearchList.main(SearchList.java:38)```
````

Comment: Just as a side note: `if (input == iterator.next()) {System.out.println(iterator.next());}` will advance the iterator 2 times

Comment: you'll need to show more code, for instance, where you declared your iterator variable

Comment: done @Stultuske

Comment: thanks for the advice @Lino - I'll use a var instead?

Comment: @berney_mark yes, else you'll encounter a `NoSuchElementException` or just skip elements and find nothing

Comment: Issue here that you created iterator at the start, then modified the list. Don't do that. In search method get iterator and work on it.

Comment: thanks @IfOnly - you solved my problem!

Comment: @berney_mark Don't put SOLVED in the question title, this is not forum, rather accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking the check icon, next to its score. Maybe also read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @berney_mark Added it as a answer. If it helped you then accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you created an `iterator` at the start, then modified the list.

**Solution:** In the `search` method get the `iterator` and work on it.

Answer (score 4):

You create the iterator (when initializing the class instance) and after that you modify the underlying list.
The iterator doesn't like that.

As the javadoc says:

*The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.*